# Reload data in UITableView without blocking UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview

My app is getting a feed of JSON data quite big representing thousands of products data. After parsing and saving data in CoreData (all in background threads), displaying data in `UITableView` after parsing block the UI since it's done in the main thread. But the problem is that the UI remains blocked for few seconds which is not user friendly. So how do you suggest I can handle reloading data without blocking UI?

```
//...
//After parsing data, reload UITableView
[self.tView reloadData];
```

**EDIT:**

I may re-explain my issue, after parsing data, reloading data, `UITableView` object display all data. Then UI is blocked for few seconds before I can finally use the app again.

here is my relevant code:

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
    //Parse data
    [self.tView reloadData];//Display data
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    //Save data
    }];

    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,NSError *error, id JSON){
    //
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: Is it the call to `reloadData` itself that's taking up the several seconds?

Comment: Yes actually, after displaying data into `UITableView`, the UI is blocked for few seconds

Comment: Also, is your view controller using a NSFetchedResultsController or are you manually fetching objects and storing them in an array? Second question, you said your data processing is handled in background threads.  Does this mean all of your changes are done in child contexts? And also is your persistent storage coordinator  linked to a context in the main thread or background thread. If it is in the main thread, the actual saving to disk could be blocking your ui

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, please have a look. Actually I use MagicalRecord to save data.

Comment: Are you using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @sangony: I see, yes I am using the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and according to apple documentation it can cause performance issue for table view displaying a huge number of rows: `There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of the rowHeight property. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on `sangony` comment, it turns out that the call of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method affect performance especially with my case where I deal with over than 3000 rows. here is Apple documentation related to that:

```
    There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of
 the rowHeight property. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls 
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a
 significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 
1000 or more).
```

From other threads discussing similar issues, I can get rid of performance issues by assigning the row height on the table view property:

```
self.tView.rowHeight = 200.0;
```

And of course, remove the implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` otherwise it will override the `rowHeight` property. Note that this solve my problem only in case I deal with single row height. So this cannot help in case where I need to apply more than one row height value, where `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSThread` to call a method in which you fetch Json data and after fetching, reload the table in the same method.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(GetJsonDataAndReload) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

So,this process will not block user interaction.